# Sort dictionary in Python based on other dictionary keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have two dictionary `x` and `y`

Input -

```
x = {"a":1, "b": 2, "c:3", "d":5}

y = {"c":3000, "a":10000}
```

Expected Output -

```
y = {"a":10000, "c":3000}
```

The orders of key of dictionary `y` should be based on order of keys in `x` dictionary
These two dictionary are coming from different source.

**Edit -`y` will have only keys that are already present in x, Also the values of key in y will be  different than x**

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: What about the values corresponding to these keys? Are they always the same? Do they have to?

Comment: Values will always be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work only in the recent versions of python

```
y = { key: y[key] for key in x if key in y}
```

For earlier versions you can check [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the keys and values of x and check if the key exists within y.

```
y = {key: y[key] for key, value in x.items() if key in y}
```

Comment: Note that this is not the expected output, as clarified in the last edit of the question.

Comment: Now it gives the expected output. However, I think the answer of napuzba is better